# How to submit text input inside <div> class element (wysiwyg editor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, wysiwyg

am using `summernote (wysiwyg) text editor`. In previous editors value could be submitted using `<textarea>`. The current editor only use `<div>` element and if I replace the `<div>` class with `<textarea>` the editor stop to work.
The summernote code is

And my textarea is `<textarea name='candidate_description'></textarea>`

My form is submitted by JavaScript function

```
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="#" method="post" accept-  charset="utf-8" id="electroal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <script>
    function submitForm(action){
    document.getElementById('electroal').action = action;
    document.getElementById('electroal').submit();
    }
    </script>

            <a href="javascript:history.go(0)" class="btn btn-default"> <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> <b>Refresh</b></a>
            <button type="submit" onclick="submitForm('<?php echo $link[0]; ?>')"></i>Save</button>
            <button type="submit" onclick="submitForm('<?php echo $link[1]; ?>')"></i>Cancel</button>

<div class="form-group input-xxx-x-wider">
    <h6><strong>Description (500 max) <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star red" ></i></strong></h6>
        <div class="widget-main no-padding">
            <div id="summernote"></div>
        </div>
    <textarea name="candidate_description"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group input-x-wider">
    <h6><strong>Status <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star red" ></i></strong>| <i>Enable to use or Disable to use later </i></h6>
    <label>
        <input name="candidate_status" value="9" type="radio" checked="checked" class="colored-success">
        <span class="text"> Enabled</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="candidate_status" value="10" type="radio" class="colored-danger">
        <span class="text"> Disabled</span>
    </label>

</div>

</form>
```

I have zero knowledge in Jquery but I can try to catch up please help me.

->My main goal is to submit the the form with the text edited inside the `<div id="summernote">some edited text here</div>` element

I used `function submitForm(action)` to submit form because the links placed on `onclick="submitForm('<?php echo $link[0]; ?>')"` are dynamic and changes according to who login.

On web browser it looks like

```
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="electroal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <script>
    function submitForm(action){
    document.getElementById('electroal').action = action;
    document.getElementById('electroal').submit();
    }
    </script>

    <button type="submit" onclick="submitForm('http://localhost/ANU_ELECTRAL1/candidate/save')">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="submitForm('http://localhost/ANU_ELECTRAL1/candidate')">Cancel</button>

<div class="form-group input-xxx-x-wider">
    <h6><strong>Description (500 max) <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star red" ></i></strong></h6>
        <div class="widget-main no-padding">
            <div id="summernote"></div>
        </div>
    <textarea name="candidate_description"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group input-x-wider">
    <h6><strong>Status <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star red" ></i></strong>| <i>Enable to use or Disable to use later </i></h6>
    <label>
        <input name="candidate_status" value="9" type="radio" checked="checked" class="colored-success">
        <span class="text"> Enabled</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="candidate_status" value="10" type="radio" class="colored-danger">
        <span class="text"> Disabled</span>
    </label>

</div>

</form>
```

Comment: What is your function `submitForm()`?  What does the form look like? Give us some more actual code please.

Comment: I used the function for submitting the form since the `url` to where the form should be sent is dynamic and changes frequently.. **IT'S ONLY FOR SUBMITTING THE FORM**. On web browser it looks like.. 

`<button type="submit" onclick="submitForm('http://localhost/ANU_ELECTRAL1/candidate/save')">Save</button>`